# regex replace string which includes incremental value

Tags: html, regex, string, alt, calibre

I am trying to create a regular expression in order to replace the alt attribute inside an image tag, for all images, which will include text and a number, starting from 1 and counting all the images - (which will always be a 3 digit number)

I have this

```
<img class="class1" src="image1.png" alt="sel5.tif"/>
<img class="class2" src="image2.png" alt="7.tif"/>
<img class="class3" src="image3.png" alt="whatever.tif"/>
```

And I would like this as an output

```
<img class="class1" src="image1.png" alt="image_1"/>
<img class="class2" src="image2.png" alt="image_2"/>
<img class="class3" src="image3.png" alt="image_3"/>
```

I have written this `alt=(['"].*?[^"]*\")` which seems to be working in finding `alt="anything"` but I have trouble in the replacement to `alt="image_1"` etc.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Which language environment are you using? JavaScript?

Comment: I am using Calibre (an editor for ebooks), so I just need the regular expressions to use them in the 'find and replace option'

Comment: There is no numbering possibility with regex, so you should probably look at changing the source of your data. I added the `calibre` tag to your question is it is quite essential information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(<.*src=)(['"](.*?)(\d+)([^"]*)\").*\/>
```

with this replacement:

```
$1$2 alt="$3_$4$5" />
```

See it [online](https://regex101.com/r/CTVqDO/1).